# Faster alternative to Convert.FromBase64String?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to convert a `base64` string to `byte array` using

```
Convert.FromBase64String
```

However, it returns me

> System.OutOfMemoryException error when the Base64String contain large size (100MB+-)

Is there any alternative way to overcome this issue?

Comment: look here !!https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/83c6c7c7-ff7e-4941-8d7e-51cd78da6e77/convertfrombase64string-throws-systemoutofmemoryexception?forum=netfxbcl...hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your calls to Convert.FromBase64String into smaller chunks, maybe ~50MB worth, and adding to your byte array as you go. That should limit the memory usage as the string is decoded.

If you still experience memory problems you may need to try writing the results to disk as you go.

Comment: Is there any Alternative method for using frombase64string ?

Comment: You could try [FromBase64Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.frombase64transform.aspx). It makes using input and output filestreams easier.

Comment: @rafeek If this helped you, please accept it as an answer so others can find it.